# Move files into folders with name of file (in a network location)

Tags: windows, command-line

I use this batch file all the time. It puts all files into their own folder with the name of the file.

`@echo off
for %%f in (*) do (
md "%%~nf"
move "%%f" "%%~nf"
) >nul 2>&1`

It only works in the location where the .bat file is located.
Is there any way to make it work with files in a network location?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `(*)` by `(C:\path\*)`.

Or, if you want to pass the folder as an argument, change it to
`(%1\*)` and call the script by:

```
C:\path\script.bat "C:\folder\path"
```

References :

- [Batch Script - Variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_variables.htm)
- [Variable Substitution](https://riptutorial.com/batch-file/example/12859/variable-substitution)