# How to batch create folders to move in a .zip file and a .pdf sharing the same name (minus extension)

Tags: windows, batch, zip

I have about 1000 ESRI shapefiles and each one is associated with a written report that I have saved as a pdf.

The zipped file and the associated pdf share the same filename (minus the extension).

I would like to be able to batch create a `\folder` of the same name and move both the `.zip` file and the `.pdf` to the `\folder`.

I tried the short script I found **[here](https://superuser.com/questions/1744350/move-files-into-folders-with-name-of-file-in-a-network-location)**:

```bash
@echo off

for %%f in (*) do (
     md "%%~nf"
     move "%%f" "%%~nf"
   ) >nul 2>&1
```

But it created one `\folder` for the `\.zip` file and onenother for the `\.pdf` file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: here's a snip of the files that I'm experimenting with]

---

The names are similar, but they are **NOT** the same in their entirety:

```
44LD0027_Ph1_TAA_08-00_SPEX_99-05_STPL_01-14.zip
                ↨                     ↨
44LD0027_Ph1_TAA 08-00_SPEX 99-05_STPL 01-14.pdf

  
44LD0109-44LD0371-44LD0421_Phl_TAA 01-01.pdf 
                                  ↨
44LD0109-44LD0371-44LD0421_Phl_TAA_01-01.zip
```

Comment: When I see 3 answers that were tested by their authors, and I myself test the alternatives besides mine, and so that the 3 do not work specifically for the author, and one works by "choosing the extension" that wants to work, I am firm that changes, edits were made. If applicable, [edit your **question**](https://superuser.com/posts/1812900/edit) and add specific and necessary editing information.

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [edit]

From comments it transpires the files are not the same due to spaces not matching in some filenames thus they need change to common underscore and in keeping with the use of forfiles the first 2 commands needs to be (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26940715/10802527)

```
forfiles /m *.pdf /C "cmd /e:on /v:on /c set \"Phile=@file\" & if @ISDIR==FALSE ren @file !Phile: =_!"
forfiles /m *.zip /C "cmd /e:on /v:on /c set \"Phile=@file\" & if @ISDIR==FALSE ren @file !Phile: =_!"
```

[image]

### Then

You could try the following one liner so first decide if zip or pdf is the more prevalent using a simple

```
echo PDF & dir *.pdf|find "File(s)"& echo ZIP &dir *.zip|find "File(s)"
```

**Then the main program** swap .zip for .pdf whichever is greater

```
forfiles /M *.zip /C "cmd /r if not exist @fname/*.@ext md @fname & move @fname.* @fname"
```

Comments suggest it will choke but not in my test, moving 1000 + 1000 fileNAMEs (move is done by renaming in hard drive MFT) is fairly slow on this old 50% CPU driven by steam Win10x32, so never expected more than slow and steady. but I find Powershell much slower. About 2 to 8 minutes for the full 2000 files.

So processor consumption is only what it is used to, flipping between 2-4 threads. Here we see it has reached test file pair 173.
[image]

Result with OP filenames (plus one)
[image]

**Words of Caution**
Beware Acrobat will very likely have problems when filenames get close to 260 characters **including pathname** so ensure if filenames are long you run in a folder closer to C:\root and use local folder not a one synced drive or user desktop folder. If files are on a server the "move" (sector rename) should be done in that environment not from afar.

Answer (score 0):

If I assumed right each ESRI file is inside a zip with a corresponding pdf file right?

It checks each zip file and if there is not a folder with the same name as the zip it first creates one and then moves the zip and corresponding pdf to that folder...

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.zip) do (
                       IF NOT EXIST "%%~na" md "%%~na"
                       move "%%~na.zip" "%%~na"
                       move "%%~na.pdf" "%%~na"
                      )
exit
```

Comment: Ricardo Bohner, thanks for this. I tried it out but this script only moved the .zip file into the folder. The .pdf did not move

Comment: @Steve T Are you 100% sure that your pdf files have exactly the same name.pdf? Because your report submitted to the code that works with zip, suggests that they do not have the same name, otherwise it would work.

Comment: Yes, they have exactly the same name.

Comment: @SteveT This states the opposite:: `move "%%~na.zip" "%%~na"` and `move "%%~na.pdf" "%%~na"` in the current code where it says it works for zip files

Comment: @lo-ol I'm not sure I follow. The script creates the folder, then moves the .zip into the folder, but the .pdf does not move for me. I copied in a snip of the folder contents that I'm experimenting with into my original question

Comment: They are not the same name, some places in string name had space!

Comment: @lo-ol You are absolutely right! How did I not notice that before. My apologies to everyone for wasting your time.

Comment: @SteveT 
The question is answered here, but as sometimes the differences are minimal, siminar is understood as the same, it happens, relax. You are welcome, and your question will be answered more appropriately from now on.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off

cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Folder"

for %%i in =;( *.zip );= do set "_n=%%~ni" & 2>nul md .\"%%~ni" & 2>nul =;(
     %ComSpec% /v /q /s /c "call move /y "%%_n:_=?%%.*" .\"%%~ni" 1>nul ");=
```

---

**1.** Enter the target folder of your task, if the folder is the same as where you are going to put the bat, then enter the folder where the bat is:

```bash
:: Enter the target folder ::
cd /d "D:\The\Full\Path\To\Folder"

:: Or, enter the folder where the batch file is ::
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

---

**2.** Use a loop that lists your `.zip` files one by one at a time:

```bash
for %%i in =;( *.zip );= do ...
```

---

**3.** For each `.zip` listed, save the name of your `.zip` (`"%%~ni"`) in a variable of your file:

```bash
 for ... ( *.zip ) do set ".\%%~ni.pdf" & ... ( ... )
```

---

**4.** Create a folder with the name of your file `.\zip`, omitting (`2>nul`) any messages that *`the folder already exists`* (considering the possibility in cases of multiple executions and duplicity of name present between executions):

```bash
if ... 2>nul md .\"%%~ni" ( 
                      ... )
```

---

**5.** Expand the variable using substring to replace any `_` in the `.zip` name with the wildcard `?`, which will suit cases where you have spaces in the name and also underscores::

```bat
%ComSpec% ... "... move /y "%%_n:_=?%%.*"   ... "
```

**6.** Invoke a new command interpetrator call already enabling the expansion delay at runtime to behave your command with substrings when moving your files:

```bat
%ComSpec% /v /q /s /c "call move /y "%%_n:_=?%%.*" .\"%%~ni" 1>nul "
```

---

**Additional Resources:**

- [`cd /d`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`if /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`md /? | mkdir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)
- [Redirection in Batch Files](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - [`|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)
- [`cmd /?` | (Refer: `%conSpec%`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)
- [Parameter Extensions (Refer: `%%~ni`)](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: ItWasntme is that you?

Comment: yEp! Meu Amigo!

Comment: What is this:  =;( *.zip );=????

Comment: @RicardoBohner literally they are just a few characters, but when it comes to composition, they are parts of a "composed" whole for a harmonious and comical attempt at a layout using code, that's it.

Comment: Before you ask, the **`.`** after **`".\"%%~ni.*".`**  are part of the composition too.

Comment: You are making a copy but the topic creator wants to move....

Comment: Its best to explain your code so its obvious to others that it is correct.

Comment: So, this one did nothing for me - no new folder created and nothing moved.

Comment: lo-ol: not to my knowledge. The other scripts run from the same location seem to partially run, they just don't seem to act on the .pdfs

Comment: @SteveT is **NOT** *`the_same name.zip`* and *`the same_name.pdf`*!